# Issue pushing/updating ADF linked service for ADB pool cluster configuration via Github action CI/CD. It is going to default setting

Tags: github-actions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

We are facing issue while pushing/updating the ADF Linked service for databrick pool cluster configuration via Github action to the live environment.

Even after setting the "clusterOption": "Autoscaling", the cluster option switched to default, "Fixed" when it is getting pushed to the live ADF. We are trying to push the parameter via JSON. This is happening in all the environment. Below is the code for the same (Masking sensitive information).

After the code is deployed to a live environment, the code "clusterOption": "Autoscaling" disappear from the code.

Can you please advise us on what may have been wrong or is this MS Azure bug.

1. The configuration which we are pushing from the Github.

```
{
    "name": "ADF_cluster_Test",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureDatabricks",
        "typeProperties": {
            "domain": "https://adb-<masked>.azuredatabricks.net",
            "authentication": "MSI",
            "workspaceResourceId": "/subscriptions/<masked>/resourceGroups/<masked>/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/<masked>",
            "instancePoolId": "<masked>",
            "newClusterNumOfWorker": "1:16",
            "newClusterSparkEnvVars": {
                "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
            },
            "newClusterVersion": "12.2.x-scala2.12",
            "clusterOption": "Autoscaling",
            "newClusterInitScripts": []
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<masked>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
}
```

2. Below is the code changes after the deployment to live environment.

```
{
    "name": "ADF_cluster_Test",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureDatabricks",
        "typeProperties": {
            "domain": "https://adb-<masked>.azuredatabricks.net",
            "authentication": "MSI",
            "workspaceResourceId": "/subscriptions/<masked>/resourceGroups/<masked>/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/<masked>",
            "instancePoolId": "<masked>",
            "newClusterVersion": "12.2.x-scala2.12",
            "newClusterNumOfWorker": "1:2",
            "newClusterSparkEnvVars": {
                "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
            },
            "newClusterInitScripts": []
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<masked>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Verified the JSON code and did some research using MS documentation, however no luck on the solution.
The majority of the solution is to deploy cluster in ADB. I tried placing the ""clusterOption": "Autoscaling"," to other lie like below instance pol id, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in ADF. The fixed or autoscaling mode is controlled by the `newClusterNumOfWorker` parameter ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-datafactory/azuredatabrickslinkedservice?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-arm-datafactory-azuredatabrickslinkedservice-newclusternumofworker)) - if it's a single number, then it's fixed size cluster, and if it's `N:M`, then it's autoscaling cluster.

Comment: @alextt_en 
I tired removing "clusterOption": "Autoscaling", and deployed, but getting the same output. its going to default settings.